# Xubuntu 14.04 network interface preferences

Tags: wireless, internet, ethernet

When I have an ethernet cable connected and WiFi pass on available network it prefers the WiFi for internet connections.  How do I make it prefer the ethernet connection?

Comment: What makes you think that it prefers WiFi? it should default to ethernet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into network manager, select "edit connections", click on the wireless network and click "edit". Click on the "general" tab and untick the option to "automatically connect to this network when available" . Do the opposite for the wired network (make sure the option to automatically connect is selected).

Answer (score 0):

Open the network manager and go to:

```
Edit connections -> wlan0 -> IPv4 Settings -> Routes...
```

Select `Use this connection only for ressources on its network` and save the changes.
Then your Wifi will only be used for local connections.

Comment: Sometimes i am using the WiFi, i want when both are available for using internet to chose the Eethernet(Wired) connection.

Comment: What makes you think it uses the wireless for internet then?

Comment: Because when i test the speed of the internet it is half of my internet power and when i stop my WiFi adapter it reconects, also when i test it with disabled WiFi adapter it is twice of the speed with WiFi.

Comment: Have you changed any settings? The default is that ethernet is used for itnernet conenctions if both are avalible.

Comment: I have not changed any settings, by default it is chosing WiFi when both are available to me.